# The term 'newman' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,

Tags: .net, powershell, jenkins, postman, newman

I'm able to execute `newman` commands from regular powershell without issue:

[image]

However, when I have Jenkins run the same script, I get the following output:

```
Checkinig prerequisites
   Chocolatey is already installed
   NodeJS is already installed
   NPM is already installed
Starting collection tests

  Testing  C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\GenericServiceWithPostman\Collections\Account Recv Microservice.postman_collection.json
newman : The term 'newman' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or 
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Program Files 
(x86)\Jenkins\workspace\GenericServiceWithPostman\RunColletionTests.ps1:47 
char:1
+ newman run $test.FullName --environment .\Environments\DEV01.postman_ ...
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (newman:String) [], CommandNotFo 
   undException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

The script that I run:

```
$tests = gci .\Collections\*postman_collection.json| Select-Object -Property FullName

foreach ($test in $tests)
 { 
 Write-Host ""
Write-Host "  Testing " $test.FullName
Start-Sleep -s 5 
newman run $test.FullName --environment .\Environments\DEV01.postman_environment.json
}
```

**The term 'newman' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet**

What am I doing wrong? How do I get it to see `newman`?

Answer (score 2):

Whatever is running Jenkins, it looks like `newman` isn't in its path. Under Jenkin's service account context, try `where.exe newman`. If it's in the path, it should return the program's location.

Comment: See the answer to this question: https://superuser.com/questions/737542/how-can-i-add-a-program-path-to-the-windows-environment-variables-for-easy-comma

Answer (score 0):

You should to install https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman

**npm install -g newman**

call your collection: newman run examples/sample-collection.json

**or use newman as library**:

const newman = require('newman'); // require newman in your project

```
// call newman.run to pass `options` object and wait for callback
newman.run({
    collection: require('./sample-collection.json'),
    reporters: 'cli'
}, function (err) {
    if (err) { throw err; }
    console.log('collection run complete!');
});
```